# Не работает сплеш скрин в андроид приложении

Tags: java, android, kotlin

Собственно сделал сплеш скрин по методике вот [отсюда](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52835697/splash-screen-approach-in-single-activity-app) (подмена темы при старте), но есть одна маааааленькая проблемка: он не работает (перед запуском происходит мини-зависание а потом сразу отображается контент).

Код весь доступен по ссылке [github.com/gohryt/sapphire](https://github.com/gohryt/sapphire), был бы очень благодарен за ответ что не так.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я делал так:

```
1) в стилях добавляешь сплеш, его указываешь как основной у мейн активности. 
2) в коде меняешь тему после окончания длительной инициализации. 

<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="dividerHorizontal">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.Launcher" parent="AppTheme">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="dividerHorizontal">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground" 
     android:gravity="fill|center">@drawable/ic_logo</item>
</style>
```

в манифесте у активности задаешь тему для сплеша.

```
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.Launcher"
        ....
     />
```

после создания активности и инициализации меняешь тему на основную и загружаешь разметку. не раньше. иначе действительно моргнет и не заметишь.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ....тут длительная инициализация
    setTheme(R.style.AppTheme_NoActionBar);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    ....тут смена сплеша на содержимое активности. 
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
 }
```

Comment: Так, помогло частично, проблема теперь в том, что когда я пишу в дровейбл адрес векторной картинки (<vector>smthng</vector>) он показывает эту картинку прямо посередине во весь размер экрана, плюс снизу и сверху выходит как-бы прозрачная дыра. А дровейбл с леер-лист внутри упрямо не показывает.

Comment: ну сложную картинку не факт что будет правильно рисовать, я градиентом рисовал фон и инкскейпом векторизовал растр, причем по минимуму чтобы был размер.